# Synchronising the cached pages with the latest pages in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html

I have cached some html pages on the browser using the HTML5 AppManifest, now my requirement is without changing the AppManifest file i want to download only those files that is different from the cached one i.e synchronising the changed files. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fear this is not possible. The design of caching is controlled by app manifest. You can try `applicationCache.update()`, but this too depends on app manifest change.